# Accessing historical top 20 users information

Tags: support, tags, top-users, rankings

Is there a way to access historical top 20 users information like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/topusers) but for any given historical date (since SE and the tag exist)?

I mean the "top [tag] answerers in last 30 days" ranking, not the all-time top users per tag (although that may also be interesting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to download and query old data dumps, I fear.

You could try and reconstruct rankings at specific points in time from the current data dump (on http://data.stackexchange.com) but since the dump doesn't contain deleted posts they would be (reasonable) estimates. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/3525/top-answerers-for-a-given-tag) could be a starting point, but you'd have to aggregate the votes manually rather than rely on the denormalised aggregate values.

There are no pre-baked historical rankings.